# Heroku App (Express React SSR) crashed

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I am trying to run my simple node app on Heroku.
Here is my **server.js**(starter point):

```
require('babel-register')

const express = require('express')
const React = require('react')
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server')
const ReactRouter = require('react-router')
const StaticRouter = ReactRouter.StaticRouter
const _ = require('lodash')
const fs = require('fs')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
const baseTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./index.html')
const template = _.template(baseTemplate)
const App = require('./js/App').default

const server = express()
server.use('/_public', express.static('./_public'))

server.use((req, res) => {
  const context = {}
  const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    React.createElement(StaticRouter, {location: req.url,
      context: context},
    React.createElement(App))
  )

  res.write(template({body: body}))
  res.end()
})

console.log('listening on port', PORT)
```

Here is the **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "medium",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "SSR react static website",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "dev": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "lint": "eslint js/**/*.js server.js",
    "watch": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3"
  },
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-disqus-thread": "^0.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-google-maps": "^7.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.1.3",
    "reactstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8"
...
}
```

In the console it prints app is starting at xxxx port. But then the app crashes with the following message

```
2017-05-29T10:15:13.241869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=medium-if-ua.herokuapp.com request_id=bc8294c4-4754-4875-8cdb-d6921212f7bb fwd="178.136.244.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small changes I've made in *server.js* :
 1. `server.listen(PORT)` - was deleted by chance, that's why node server exited all the time. [image]
 2. added presets to `babel-register` package:
[image]
And after all everything works fine )

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the issue by wrapping the rendering in the `try/catch` block and sending the error with a stack trace:

```
server.use((req, res) => {
  try {
    const context = {}
    const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      React.createElement(StaticRouter, 
        {location: req.url, context: context},
        React.createElement(App)
      )
    )

    res.write(template({body: body}))
    res.end()
  } catch (error) {
    const result = [error.message, error.stack].join('\r\n')
    res.send(result)
  }
})
```

Comment: Please try `heroku restart` as it seems to help other people in cases like that.

Comment: No it doesn't help (

Comment: Please add logging: `heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=debug` and see what is causing the issue. Seems like an issue with some imports or reading a file.